# eclipse plugin: run command in console, get stdin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm making an eclipse plugin where I want to run a system command, and have the output of the command go to the eclipse console.  I know how to do this via http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F

The problem I don't know how to solve, is to allow interactive input from the console for this command.

In essence, I want to kick off a command which runs in the console. The user can interact with this command (via stdin).  I then want my plugin code to get a callback when the command has finished (or user has manually stopped/terminated the command in the console).  Getting the return code of the completed program would be nice as well.

For simplicity sake, lets use the unix 'passwd' command as the example (this is the first common cmd I could think of that both has output and prompts for input).  I don't need to hide the stdin however.

For reference, the command I'm trying to call is the [CakePHP bake shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got yourself a MessageConsole, like in the FAQ. Then it should be possible to use `messageConsole.getInputStream().read()` in a loop to get your input (but I have not tested this). See also the documentation of the [IOConsoleInputStream](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/console/IOConsoleInputStream.html) for more options.

On the other hand I'm not sure why you are creating your own plugin to do that. The standard console implementation in Eclipse does exactly what you want. You can see that by running a small Java application, where you can use that console for input and output as well.

Comment: I'm kina a Java noob so sorry in advance. Idea here would be to take that input stream and somehow pipe it back to the running command? Isn't there someway to pass a command off to the console via org.eclipse.ui.console and it handles input/output to the console?

As for why: I'm integrating some features into a CakePHP plugin I'm writing. Want to do stuff like right click on Model>bake (which generates all the code, relationships etc).  I am familiar with run external tools (and have gotten it working with bake before: http://rynop.com/setting-up-eclipse-36-for-cakephp-13-developm)